# The stdout of a command run in sub-shell is not being captured by "$()"

Tags: bash, shell

So for one reason or another, I wrote this script to get programmatic descriptions of an sbt project.

```
#!/bin/bash
project_name="$(sbt project | tail -n1 | cut -d' ' -f 2- | sed 's!\s*(in build.*)!!')"
project_version="$(sbt version | tail -n1 | cut -d' ' -f 2-)"

echo $project_name
echo $project_version

echo "find . -name ${project_name}*.jar"    
echo "Find: $(find . -name ${project_name}*.jar)"
```

However, the final echo (which runs `find` in `$()`) is not giving me any output, despite ostensibly running the same command as is printed above it.

I've run the above script using `bash -ex` too, so:

- I know the printed `find ...` command works i.e. the file it's looking for exists
- I know that `${project_name}` is expanded correctly inside `"$()"`
- I know that echo `Echo: "$(echo ${project_name})"` works
- With -ex, the final find is printed as `++ find . -name 'my-test-app*.jar'`

But the final `echo "Find: $(find . -name ${project_name}*.jar)"` never returns anything. It just prints `Find:`.

Comment: What is your `-ex` output? Does quoting `${project_name}*.jar` like `'${project_name}*.jar'` help?

Comment: It would need to be `"${project_name}*.jar"`, no? We want the expansion to be done before `find` is invoked, after all, so `'${project_name}*.jar'` (suppressing expansion altogether) doesn't make sense.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Indeed.

Comment: By the way -- `printf '%q ' find . -name ${project_name}*.jar; printf '\n'` is a better way to tell exactly what `find . -name ${project_name}*.jar` will do, as opposed to `echo "find . -name ${project_name}*.jar"`. (Of course, running with `bash -x` tells you that too).

Comment: ...using `echo` doesn't show you the difference between `"foo bar"` and `"foo" "bar"`; `printf '%q '` does.

Comment: In this case the use of `%q` for that printf wouldn't have been the key factor the lack of quoting on the arguments would have been (so `echo find . -name ${project_name*.jar` would have been as useful for this specific issue).

Comment: not sure if my answer solved your issue. Did it?

Comment: @fedorqui - I came back to it the next day, and discovered that sbt was emitting colours, but I wasn't seeing them for some reason. So sed wasn't stripping them out, and so the $project_name didn't match a file name.

Comment: @MrBones aaaah makes sense. This sometimes happens because your original `sbt` has some alias that colourizes the output. For example once I was having weird outputs from `grep` and then I found out my alias `alias grep="grep --color='always'"`. If it is the case, you can circunvent it using `\grep`, `\sbt`...

Comment: @fedorqui It's because sbt doesn't do sensible things when its output is piped :(, unlike say grep, which is sensible when --color=auto

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to quote, because otherwise your `find` command is like `find . something*.jar`, that will expand without proper control:

```
echo "Find: $(find . -name "${project_name}*.jar")"
                           ^                    ^
```

I did some tests and it works fine to me, whereas it does not without these quotes.

#### Test

```
$ touch a1.jar
$ touch a123.jar
```

Without quotes:

```
$ find . -name a*jar
find: paths must precede expression: a1.jar
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

With quotes:

```
$ find . -name "a*jar"
./a123.jar
./a1.jar
```

Comment: @MrBones, in the general case, no, using a subshell does not solve those problems. Your edit only has a subset of the quotes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The `find`'s option `-name` require a pattern. But in your code the `*` is expanded by the shell, before lauching find.

So you have two choices :

- use quotes : `echo "Find: $(find . -name "${project_name}*.jar")"`
- or escape the `*` : `echo "Find: $(find . -name ${project_name}\*.jar")`